# Objective-C++ Not Compiling

Tags: c++, objective-c, compilation, compiler-errors, objective-c++

I'm trying to build an app for ios. I already have a library written in C++ and I want to use it in my application. So naturally I need to write some Objective-C++.
I'm getting some weird errors from the following simple file:
Engine.mm:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Yeah...
These are the kind of errors I'm getting:

```
CFCalendar.h:70:28: Missing ',' between enumerators
CFCalendar.h:71:28: Redefinition of enumerator '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_5_0'
CFError.h:69:43: Expected ';' after top level declarator
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now
```

As you can guess, there are a lot more of these errors.
Here is my configuration: 
Compiler: Apple LLVM 4.1.
C Dialect: GNU99
C++ Dialect: GNU++98
C++ Standard Library: libstdc++ (GNU C++ Standard Library)
Compile Sources as: According to file type
I tried many other variants but none have worked out for me.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks, Tal

Comment: Yes. As it says in the question, the file is named Engine.mm

Answer (score 2):

At the end it turned out to be an Xcode bug. I simply deleted the file and created it again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error:

```
CFCalendar.h:71:28: Redefinition of enumerator '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_5_0'
```

I have seen similar redefinition errors when I import the header in both the .m and .h files.  Not sure if that could be your problem, could you post snippets of the imports of both the .mm and .h?

Comment: The .mm doesn't include anything besides Foundation.h. I tried to narrow down the error by removing includes from the .mm.

Comment: Does your .mm file have its own header file?  Or is it a single source file?

Comment: What is the content of the prefix header file (the file with the `.pch` extension)?